# How to get record where join does not exist?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

how to select record from one table when there is no matching record in another table.

```
$bookings->getQuery()
                ->join('consultation', 'consultation.booking_id', '=', 'bookings.id')
                ->whereRaw('bookings.booking_date  >= CURDATE()')
                ->select('bookings.*')
                ->groupBy('bookings.id');
```

In above query i am trying to get bookings only when there is no consultation exists for that booking. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using sub_query

```
->whereNotIn('id', function($query){
  $query->select('booking_id')
  ->from('consultation')
  ->distinct();})->get();
```